# Infragistics Populate DropDown menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, infragistics

Using VS2013 with Infragistics, is it possible to programmatically populate the *UltraDropDownButton* without the need of a database? Searching the documentation on how to do this returns no avail, nor does a google search. Everything listed suggests using `.Items.Add();` Which is not available when trying. I have tried:

[image: no Member .Items found]

I apologize for the picture, but it's a more of a visual problem as the member method `.Items` does not exist, the same with using:

`SearchParams.`  There is no member method for Items nor Add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is possible, but you may have to do some work to get it to appear correctly.

Here is some sample code that I threw together real quick

```
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "Button 1" });
    panel.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "Button 2" });

    UltraPopupControlContainer container = new UltraPopupControlContainer();
    container.PopupControl = panel;

    ultraDropDownButton1.PopupItem = container;
```

Here is a screenshot of the created form.  Only 1 button is visible, so that's where you'll have to do some work to make sure it meets your requirements.

[image: example form]

I found all the info necessary to throw that together on the infragistics site.

[UltraDropDownButton](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.Misc.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraDropDownButton.html) Docs

[UltraPopupControlContainer](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/HTML/Infragistics4.Win.Misc.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraPopupControlContainer.html) Docs

[Usage Guide](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/HTML/WinDropDownButton_Using_the_DropDown_Button.html)

The key information is from the second bullet point from the Usage guide.  The example in the second link uses a tree as an example of adding an item to the button.

> Add a second control that will displayed when the drop-down button is
>   clicked. If the interface of the drop-down will consist of multiple
>   WinForms controls, you will want to use a container control such as a
>   Panel. (You may also want to add the contained controls to the
>   container at this point, constructing the interface that will be
>   displayed by the drop-down.) You can also use a non-container control
>   such as a **ListView** or an **UltraWinGrid** as the drop-down.