# Multi-Column DropDown Not in UltraGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

Is there a way to do a multi-column dropdown (preferably with text suggestions, like UltraComboEditor) but, not in a grid cell?

I can do it in a grid cell using the UltraDropDown control but, it seems this only wants to live within an ultragrid.

[image]

I found this documentation: http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2015.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v15.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraCombo.html

Which says: 
*The UltraCombo control can be used as the UltraGridColumn.ValueList of an UltraGrid column, but it is intended for use as a standalone control on a form. To provide a multi-column dropdown list in a grid cell, use the UltraDropDown control.*

But... what I'm looking for is a dropdown control, not in a grid, with multi columns.  Basically what's shown above but not in a grid cell.

Any suggestions even some search terms to research further would be very much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with help from this post: [Infragistics Populate DropDown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416859/infragistics-populate-dropdown-menu)

```
//create and ultradropdown item and populate it
UltraDropDown udd = new UltraDropDown();
udd.DataSource = PrefTags.FindAllOrdered();

//create a popup container and add the ultradropdown item to the 'popupcontrol' property of the container
UltraPopupControlContainer container = new UltraPopupControlContainer();
container.PopupControl = udd;

//add the container to an ultradropdownbutton control
uddbInstrumentNo.PopupItem = container;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use devexpress GridLookUpEdit as shown on the link below.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsGridLookUpEdittopic

[devexpress gridlookupedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh3I5.png)

Comment: Thanks bu, I'm looking for something not in a grid, just a dropdown control that is not in a grid

Comment: Yes this is a dropdown control that is not in a grid. Have you checked it?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into Infragistics controls what you need is [UltraCombo](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/wincombo-about-wincombo). This is a multicolumn dropdown which you may place anywhere in your application as a stand-alone control.